# OTR Radio - spaceship self destruct to avoid city

Tags: story-identification, radio-play

Looking for old time radio show OTR story with this plot.  A passenger spaceship for some reason has to make the choice to self destruct because if it doesn't it will impact a major city and be like small extinction level asteroid crash.

I don't think this was a normal episode of a series like dimension x because I've listened to the classic major series, but maybe I've missed it.  I heard this from a school library tape set of radio shows that included a lot of radio shows and Orson Welles stuff.

Comment: It's the novelette "Sound Decision" by Robert Silverberg and Randall Garrett. [You can read it here](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v58n02_1956-10_Gorgon776). It was adapted to radio (drastically abridged) as an episode of Exploring Tomorrow which [you can listen to here](https://archive.org/details/Exploring_Tomorrow).

Comment: Yes that has to be it.  Thank you John!